# Top 1 distinct rows from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
ID Username     ModifiedDate

1  A.BEENA     2009-12-07 04:48:17.980
2  A.BEENA     2009-11-17 06:02:27.443
3  Abhilash    2009-12-07 04:48:17.980
4  abhilash.r  2009-12-07 04:48:17.980
5  AJI         2009-11-17 06:02:27.443
6  haris       2009-12-07 04:48:17.980
7  haris       2009-11-17 06:02:27.443
```

I want to select details of all distinct users order by ModifiedDate.

I need output like this

```
   1 A.BEENA      2009-12-07 04:48:17.980
   3 Abhilash     2009-12-07 04:48:17.980
   4 abhilash.r   2009-12-07 04:48:17.980
   5 AJI          2009-11-17 06:02:27.443
   6 haris        2009-12-07 04:48:17.980
```

Please help me

Comment: Are there other columns as well or you actually having only username and date?

Comment: If this is a large table, be sure to give it the proper indexing based on the solution you choose.

Comment: In that particular case you should point that out, because based on your example data, solution is rather trivial if one doesn't know that you want the whole row of data which belongs to the row containing the maximum modified date.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. i modified the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
WITH CTE (DuplicateCount,Username,ModifiedDate) AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC) AS DuplicateCount,
        Username,
        ModifiedDate
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount = 1
```

Comment: +1: This will actually give you the whole record with maximum modified date.

Comment: No, it gives you three columns of DuplicateCount (always 1), Username and ModifiedDate. It could be modified very easily to include any additional columns but has been marked as the answer without them.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Username, MAX(ModifiedDate) AS LastModified
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Username
```

This will give the output you mention, which appears to show the most recent date for each username.

Comment: But this will only work if he only requires maximum modified date and not when he requires the whole row of the maximum modified date (hence my comment on the question). I think he presented a simplified example of his data. He should've added one more column to add to complexity of the problem.

Comment: Yes, but that's all that's currently asked for. If he wants the ID too then the answer of course would be different.

Comment: @CodeMyMoonlight: My anticipations were obviously correct. At times when the question isn't clear enough it's better to ask first and then answer.

Comment: I've voted up the other answer as it's more flexible, but I do not see that your anticipations were obviously correct - he's quite possibly simply stated the source table has more than those three columns.

Comment: Hmmm...wasn't there a delete button next to answers once upon a time?

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight: I totally agree with you. I've also commented OP about the same problem. Questions have to be clear to get valuable answers.

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight: I think they are available only until there's not accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(ID int, Username varchar(50), ModifiedDate datetime)

INSERT INTO #temp(ID, Username, ModifiedDate)
VALUES
(1,  'A.BEENA',     '2009-12-07 04:48:17.980'),
(2,  'A.BEENA',     '2009-11-17 06:02:27.443'),
(3,  'Abhilash',    '2009-12-07 04:48:17.980'),
(4,  'abhilash.r',  '2009-12-07 04:48:17.980'),
(5,  'AJI',         '2009-11-17 06:02:27.443'),
(6,  'haris',       '2009-12-07 04:48:17.980'),
(7,  'haris',       '2009-11-17 06:02:27.443')

SELECT t.Username, t.ModifiedDate
FROM #temp t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #temp WHERE Username = t.Username AND ModifiedDate > t.ModifiedDate)
```